# upper bound for infimum of integral

Tags: inequalities, integration, hilbert-spaces

I was reading this [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/324561/infimum-upper-bound/324567#324567?newreg=5f82e92f7ee74dd9950a76c9940ef088) , where the following question is discussed:

Let $h:[0,1] \rightarrow[0,1]$ be a $C^{1}$ function such that $h^{\prime}(x)<0$ for all $x \in(0,1)$. Then,
$$
\inf _{f \in \mathcal{H}}\left(\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} h(|x-y|)(f(x)-f(y))^{2} d x d y\right)<2 \int_{0}^{1} h(x) d x
$$
where $\mathcal{H}=\left\{f \in L^{2}([0,1]): \int_{0}^{1} f(t) d t=0\right.$ and $\left.\int_{0}^{1} f^{2}(t) d t=1\right\}$

Someone in the answers proved this by explicitly finding an $f \in \mathcal{H}$. Their proof starts by arguing that
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} h(|x-y|)(f(x)-f(y))^{2} d x d y-2 \int_{0}^{1} h(x) d x=2 D_{f}(h)
$$
where
$$
D_{f}(h):=\int_{0}^{1} d x \int_{x}^{1} d y h(y-x)(f(x)-f(y))^{2}-\int_{0}^{1} h .
$$

This raised a couple of questions for me, since I'm working on something similar:

1. why does this hold?
   $$D_{f}(h):=\int_{0}^{1} d x \int_{x}^{1} d y h(y-x)(f(x)-f(y))^{2}-\int_{0}^{1} h$$
   I checked it for a few functions and I'm convinced that it is in fact true, but I can't prove it.
2. If $h(x,y)=h(|x-y|)+E(x,y)$, what assumptions do we need on $E(x,y)$ for the same statement to hold for $h$? For example, would it hold if $E$ was "small enough"?

I would deeply appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

We have
\begin{equation}
    I:=\int_0^1\int_0^1 h(|x-y|)(f(x)-f(y))^2\,dx\,dy =I_1+I_2, 
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    I_1&:=\int_0^1\int_0^1 1(x>y)h(|x-y|)(f(x)-f(y))^2\,dx\,dy, \\
    I_2&=\int_0^1\int_0^1 1(x<y)h(|x-y|)(f(x)-f(y))^2\,dx\,dy. 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Next,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    I_1&=\int_0^1\int_0^1 1(x>y)h(|x-y|)(f(x)-f(y))^2\,dx\,dy \\
    &=\int_0^1\int_0^1 1(x>y)h(x-y)(f(x)-f(y))^2\,dx\,dy \\ 
    &=\int_0^1\int_0^1 1(v>u)h(v-u)(f(v)-f(u))^2\,du\,dv \\ 
    &=\int_0^1\int_0^1 1(u<v)h(v-u)(f(u)-f(v))^2\,du\,dv \\ 
    &=\int_0^1\int_0^1 1(x<y)h(y-x)(f(x)-f(y))^2\,dx\,dy \\ 
    &=\int_0^1\int_0^1 1(x<y)h(|y-x|)(f(x)-f(y))^2\,dx\,dy=I_2. 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Also, reading the above multiline display backwards, we see that
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    I_2&=\int_0^1\int_0^1 1(x<y)h(y-x)(f(x)-f(y))^2\,dx\,dy \\ 
    &= \int_0^1 dx\,\int_x^1 dy\,h(y-x)(f(x)-f(y))^2.  
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
So,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    I&=I_1+I_2 \\ 
    &=2I_2=2 \int_0^1 dx\,\int_x^1 h(y-x)(f(x)-f(y))^2\,dx\,dy,  
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
which immediately implies
\begin{equation}
    \int_0^1\int_0^1 h(|x-y|)(f(x)-f(y))^2\,dx\,dy-2\int_0^1 h(x)dx \\ 
=I-2\int_0^1 h=2D_f(h),
\end{equation}
as desired.

Comment: I see, thank you very much! Do you have an idea about the second question as well?

Comment: @Gordafarid : Your second question is way too nonspecific. A question on MathOverflow (MO) should be such that it would be clear what would constitute a valid answer to it. Also, asking multiple questions in one post is not encouraged on MO. So, I suggest you remove your second question and then perhaps post it elsewhere, possibly not on MO, after giving it a good deal of thought. Meanwhile, let us finalize this matter in accordance with the guidelines at https://mathoverflow.net/help/accepted-answer and https://mathoverflow.net/help/someone-answers